Batch export individual monthly rasters from a raster stack in Google Earth Engine
I have the following code where I am exporting monthly images (all bands included) for the year 2018:
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/HLS/HLSL30/v002")
    .filterBounds(table);

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
print("months", months);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2018, 2018);
print("years", years);

// Map filtering and reducing across year-month combinations and convert to ImageCollection
var yrMo = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
            return collection
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
              .mean()
              .set('year',y)
              .set('month',m);
        });
    }).flatten());
print("yrMo",yrMo);

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(yrMo,
                'test', 
                {scale: 130, 
                 crs: 'EPSG:3309',
                 region: table
                })

As you can see in the following image below, there is one image per month. Each image is a raster stack containing 15 bands.

What I would like to do is to export each band separately and name it NameOfTheBand_Month. For example red_04. How can I do that?
The link to the code. The shp I am using. The product's page in google earth engine.

You are using ee.ImageCollection.fromImages, use the same structure and iterate through bands. Also, set system:index for a better exporting name:
var yrMo = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
            var img = collection
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
              .mean()
              .set('year',y)
              .set('month',m);
            var bands = img.bandNames()
            return bands.map(function(n) {
              var image = img.select([n]);
              var image = image.set('system:index',ee.String(y).cat(ee.String(m)).cat(ee.String(n)));
              return image;
            })
        });
    }).flatten());

Obviously, you can choose a better name ;)

